# Octave: For-loop error says A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave

I need to evaluate the integral from `x=-1` to `x=1` for the function `x*e^(x)*sin(pi*x)`. To do so, I'm using the Gaussian Quadrature method. This method can be summarized as the summation of the `(weights)*(function evaluated at given roots)` from `k=1` to `k=n` where `n=30`.

In my code below, the roots are found in the column vector `LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(n).x`. I'm taking the transpose because I want to perform element by element multiplication on the weights, which are stored in the *row* vector `LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(n).w`

**My code:**

```
fx = @(x) x .* e.^(-x) .* sin(pi .* x);

  for k = 1:50

    Leg(k) = (fx(LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).x))' .* LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).w;

  endfor
```

The problem is that it's giving me the error in the title, implying that there is some problem with using a scalar value of `k` and that it should match up with the size of values being multiplied, but that makes no sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it yourself in your question

> the roots are found in the column vector `LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(n).x`. I'm taking the transpose because I want to perform **element by element multiplication** on the weights, which are stored in the row vector `LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(n).w`.

You're taking the element-wise product of two vectors and the result is also going to be a vector. However, you then try to assign it to a scalar, `Leg(k)` which produces your error.

You either need to store these vectors in a 2D version of `Leg`

```
for k = 1:50
    Leg(k,:) = (fx(LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).x))' .* LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).w;
endfor
```

or perform some other operation on the element-wise multiplication result to get it to be a scalar.

```
for k = 1:50
    Leg(k) = sum((fx(LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).x))' .* LegendreGaussQuadratureConstants(k).w);
endfor
```

Comment: The first method is giving me an error: `error: script: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch` pointing to the `=` sign after `Leg(k)`. The 2nd method looks more promising. It gives me what appears to be the correct value of this integral but once for every iteration in a vector. I want this to result in a single scalar value.

Comment: Nevermind, the 2nd answer works well. Thanks for your help!